# How do I allow partial updates via POST request in Django?

Tags: python, django, serialization

Working on a small Django app and I've been asked to set up partial updates via POST request. I'm aware that PATCH works for partial updates out of the box but I don't have access to the front end and that's not what I've been asked to do.

I was told it's a quick one line change, so I'm assuming I have to update the serializer as explained in the DRF docs (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates) but I'm not sure where to do that exactly.

Serializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from cat.models import Cat
class CatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Cat
        fields = (
            'id', 'name', 'breed', 'birth_date', 'added_at', 'description')
```

Viewset:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from cat.serializers import CatSerializer
from cat.models import Cat

class CatViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Cat.objects.all().order_by('-birth_date')
    serializer_class = CatSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

The custom router is what you need. Change the router's mapping as you want. Do something like this:

```py
class CustomRouter(SimpleRouter):
    routes = [
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={
                'get': 'list',
                'post': 'create'
            },
            name='{basename}-list',
            detail=False,
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'}
        ),
        DynamicRoute(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{url_path}{trailing_slash}$',
            name='{basename}-{url_name}',
            detail=False,
            initkwargs={}
        ),
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={
                'get': 'retrieve',
                'post': 'partial_update',  # <-- this is the needed part
                'put': 'update',
                'patch': 'partial_update',
                'delete': 'destroy'
            },
            name='{basename}-detail',
            detail=True,
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'Instance'}
        ),
        DynamicRoute(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}/{url_path}{trailing_slash}$',
            name='{basename}-{url_name}',
            detail=True,
            initkwargs={}
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer! I can't seem to get this method working. All POST requests to the resource endpoint on Postman return "Method \"POST\" not allowed." Regular POST requests work fine though. I tried your code with PUT instead but received a 400 saying the other fields are required.

Comment: @Wayne, my mistake, I forget the `url_path` attribute. I updated my answer.

Comment: Ok this is strange. So that now works for partial updates, and I can still post new objects. I can also get all objects from the endpoint, but when I give a specific ID to return I get back "Method \"GET\" not allowed."

Does the url_path argument route all urls that match to this action?

Comment: It seems I found the better way. I dive deeper and understood, this is the DRF's router task. You should change the mapping part. Just add `'post': 'partial_update'` and it will work as you need.